# SURICATA - <Error> - [ERRCODE: SC_ERR_DUPLICATE_SIG(176)]

Tags: linux, ids, suricata

When i execute

```
sudo suricata -i enp0s8 -c suricata.yaml -s rules/misreglas.rules
```

Get the output:

```
<Error> - [ERRCODE: SC_ERR_DUPLICATE_SIG(176)] - Duplicate signature "drop http $HOME_NET any -> any any (msg: "HTTP DROP";)"

<Error> - [ERRCODE: SC_ERR_INVALID_SIGNATURE(39)] - error parsing signature "drop http $HOME_NET any -> any any (msg: "HTTP DROP";)" from file rules/misreglas.rules at line 1
```

misreglas.rules content

```
drop http $HOME_NET any -> any any (msg: "HTTP DROP";)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the rules like that:

```
drop ICMP any any -> 169.69.1.11 any (msg: "test";sid:10001;)
drop HTTP $HOME_NET any -> any any (msg: "HTTP DROP";sid:10002;)
```

where I put sid you have to put and sid that is not already in use.